# How to capture the word behind cursor when the cursor moves over a FlowDocumentPageViewer

Tags: c#, wpf

How to capture the word behind cursor when the cursor moves over a FlowDocumentPageViewer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the `RichTextBox` in read-only mode instead of the `FlowDocumentPageViewer`, you can get the `TextPointer` that specifies the closest insertion position for the supplied point (e.g., result of the `MouseMove` event) by calling `RichTextBox.GetPositionFromPoint`. Inspect the text content using the obtained `TextPointer`.

Other solutions will be far more complex as there is no such public API on the `FlowDocumentPageViewer` or `FlowDocument`.

Comment: ty @BionicCode. how about mouse click event instead of mouse move event in FlowDocumentPageViewer?

Comment: The event does not really matter (it must be a mouse event of course in order to obtain the current mouse pointer position). The point is that neither the FlowDocumentPageViewer nor the underlying FlowDocument defines an API to convert a screen point to a relative text position. That's why I suggest to use a read-only RichTextBox as viewer instead. The RichTextBox provides such API: RichTextBox.GetPositionFromPoint.

Comment: If rich text formatting is not required you can even use a simple (read-only) TextBox. This would further simplify text handling.

Comment: TextBox exposes a `TextBox.GetCharacterIndexFromPoint` method.